# Flutter Error: Mapbox java.lang.IllegalAccessError when building in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm building a mobile app using flutter. Because i needed a map in this project i added Mapbox Gl form pub.dev.
When i build the project in debug mode, everything works correctly but in release mode via flutter run --release or flutter build apk
i get the error below
#java.lang.IllegalAccessError

> E/AndroidRuntime(17468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(17468): Process: com.example.connectiv, PID: 17468
> E/AndroidRuntime(17468): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface
> androidx.lifecy cle.b implemented by class
> com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController is inaccessib le (declaration
> of 'com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController' appears in /data/ap
> p/~~cfRuPsC3U_WxCb2HWrdntg==/com.example.connectiv-hDsXcUANkWTvGTdp92h8zA==/base
> .apk)

here are the different versions used in the project

Flutter: flutter_windows_2.10.0-stable
Mapbox Gl: mapbox_gl: ^0.15.0.

Below my pubspect.yaml file

```
name: projectname
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  mapbox_gl: ^0.15.0
  location: ^4.2.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  circular_menu: ^1.2.3
  video_player: ^2.2.16
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/videos/
    - assets/json/
```

And finally my mapScreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

class Exemple extends StatefulWidget {
  const Exemple({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExempleState createState() => _ExempleState();
}

class _ExempleState extends State<Exemple> {
   MapboxMapController? mapController;
  var isLight = true;

  _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  _onStyleLoadedCallback() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Style loaded :)"),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
            onPressed: () => setState(
              () => isLight = !isLight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: MapboxMap(
          styleString: isLight ? MapboxStyles.LIGHT : MapboxStyles.DARK,
          accessToken: "my_mapbox_public_access_token",
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0)),
          onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoadedCallback,
        ));
  }
}
```

**Really need help, i tried many things to solve this problem but none worked**

Comment: Maybe this could help https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/573

Comment: I finally find the solution with this issue https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/638